# PYTHON IndexError : string index out of range

Tags: python

Problem statement : Write a function called censor that takes two strings, text and word, as input. It should return the text with the word you chose replaced with asterisks

Here is my code,

```
def censor(text, word):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    ans = ""

    while i<len(text):
        while text[j] == word[j]:
            j = j + 1
        if text[j+1] == " " or j+1 == len(text):
            while i<j:
                ans += "*"
                i = i + 1
            ans += " "
            i = i + 1
        else:
            while text[j] != " ":
                j = j + 1
            while i<=j:
                ans += text[i]
                i = i + 1

        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1

    return ans

print censor("how are you? you are not fine.","you")
```

But I am getting the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 27, in <module>
  File "python", line 7, in censor
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: I did the problems on codeacademy as well. This one really doesn't need to be this complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much more complicated than it needs to be. You can just do this:

```
def censor(text, censored_word):
    return text.replace(censored_word, '*'*len(censored_word))

>>> censor('How are you? Are you okay?', 'you')
'How are ***? Are *** okay?'
```

If you don't want the word `youth` to be censored but you do want `you` to be censored, here's how:

```
def censor(text, censored_word):
    repl = '*'*len(censored_word)
    return ' '.join([repl if word == censored_word else word for word in text.split()])
```

If you want to have multiple censored words:

```
def censor(text, censored_words):
    return ' '.join(['*'*len(word) if word in censored_words else word for word in text.split()])
```

When dealing with index errors, it is often helpful to **print out the index** and figure out why the index has a value not within the required bounds.

Comment: Note that this approach also replaces the to-be-censored word when it appears as part as a string, e.g. `censor("youth", "you") == "***th"`. If this is not what's supposed to happen, a better approach would be to split the text into individual words and then replace all words which equal the input.

Comment: @l4mpi I will add in a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to use `string replace` in python for replacing the string.
In your case, you should make use of word's length to match word in the text as:

```
def censor(text, word):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    ans = ""
    wl=len(word)

    while i<(len(text)):
        if word==text[i:i+wl]:
            ans=ans+'*'*wl
            i=i+wl
        else:
            ans=ans+text[i]
            i = i + 1

    return ans

print censor("how are you? you are not fine.","you")
```